# cv::split in OpenCV 2.4.1 and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I had a problem while splitting rgb image into single channels. My simple code is as following

```
    **cv::Mat src = cv::imread("D:/Test/a.jpg", 1);
std::vector<cv::Mat> img_rgb;
cv::split(src, img_rgb);
cv::imshow("a", src);**
```

My debug shows that this probem come from the split function and the following errors was throwed.
***Unhandled exception at 0x10005768 in Test_Opencv2.4.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000bc.***

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked that the image is valid after reading it with `cv::imread`?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use the other slash and escape it, plus you **always need to check the return of `imread()`**:

```
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("D:\\Test\\a.jpg", 1);
if (src.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Couldn't load image" << endl;
    // exit
}
```

Comment: I had cheked the image was loaded successfully, even it had been showed in cv::imshow() fuction. But errors were occured :(